# Trying to understand Mathematica's code and replicate in Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to understand a Mathematica code so that I can replicate it in python:

My function in  **Mathematica** -

`Deulab[c_, yh1_, a_, b_] := {c - (EULab[c, yh1, a, b] - 1) * 0.3, yh1, a, b}` where I have already defined `EULab` above.

What does the curly bracket mean and how can I interpret this code and then replicate it in python?

**Mathematica**

```
DDeulab[T_] := Deulab@@T
```

What is `@@ T` and what is it's equivalent in python?

**Mathematica**

```
Coab[yh_, a_, b_] := Last[NestList[DDeulab, {1, yh, a, b}, 50]][[1]]
```

What is `Last[NestList][[1]]` means and also it's equivalent in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the wolfram client?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/

and their reference docs?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html

{a,b,c} represents a vector.

But in this case you've 4 elements, so it looks like a list.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html

@@ represents apply

So that'd be applying a function, i.e. f[a,b,c,d]

Comment: @@ is applying the function to a,b,c,d simultaneously or one by one?

Comment: Does it matter in this case - Deulab@@T can only be singular anyway.

Convention would suggest a list be treated separately.